# .attr selector wont work in a each loop?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Here's the code:

```
  $.ajax({
      url: 'AEWService.asmx/previewAsset',
      type: "GET",
      contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
      data: json,
      success: function (json) {
          var prevObj = jQuery.parseJSON(json.d);
          setInterval(function () {
              var pId = $('#previewIframe').contents().find('[preview-id]');
              $.each(prevObj, function (i, item) {
                  pId.each(function () {
                      var pElem = this.attr("preview-id");
                      if (pElem == item.Id) {
                          $(this).html(item.Value);
                      }
                  });
              });
          }, 3000);
      }
  });
```

Comment: `this` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object. Please read the [`.each()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and have a look at the examples. Actually you already seem to know that, since you are calling `$(this).html()`...

Answer (score 5):

`this` is a DOM node, not a jQuery object. Please read the [`.each()` documentation](http://api.jquery.com/each/) and have a look at the examples.

Actually you already seem to know that, since you are calling `$(this).html()`...

Answer (score 1):

Try to change `this.attr("preview-id")` to `$(this).attr("preview-id")`

like you use this in `$(this).html(item.Value)`

Hope this help you.

Comment: Don't you mean `$(this).attr(...)`? `$this` is not defined.